# Retrieve data from Excel sheet for Artificial Neural Network training

Tags: excel, neural-network, excel-2010, vba

I started to write code for a neural network.
The training data set is in an Excel sheet - two inputs and two outputs.
I am struggling to import the data into VBA so the network can be trained.

Code for the training part

```
Private Sub Train_Click()
alpha = 0.3
mu = 0.8
n = 4
m = 4
Dim I, J, K As Integer
Dim TrainError As Double
Dim TrainingData As String
NumCases = 123
For J = 0 To NumCases - 1
For I = 0 To m
X1(J, I) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, J).String
Next I
targval(J) = X1(J, n)
Next J

Call Init(n, m)
J = 0
Do Until J = 1000 And TrainError = 0
For I = 0 To NumCases - 1
For K = 0 To n - 1
InputNeuron(K) = X1(I, K)
Next
Call HiddenInput(n, m)
Call HiddenTransfer(m)
Call OutputInput(m)
Call OutputTransfer
Call UpdateOut(I, m)
Call UpdateHidden(n, m)
TrainError = TrainError + (targval(I) - oout) ^ 2
Next I
TrainError = Sqrt(TrainError / NumCases)
If TrainError < 0.01 Then
Exit Do
End If
J = J + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Is Excel a good platform for neural network training? IIRC, Excel is single threaded, so unless you do something in COM or somehow spawn an extra thread, Excel UI is going to freeze big time?

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is to import the data, I presume the issue is inside the first loop:

```
X1(J, I) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, J).String
```

If so, you could just try to use a method that reads your data given a `Range`. You declare an array to hold the input layer:

```
Public inputv() As Double   '// the input layer data
```

and then populate it given the range of the data, lets say "C19:C27", with this method:

```
Private Sub loadInput(ByRef r As Range)

    Dim s As Range
    Set s = r.Resize(1, 1)

    // this way you can even evaluate the number of trainning examples, m
    m = r.Rows.Count


    ReDim inputv(0 To m - 1, 0 To n - 1)
    Dim i, j As Integer

    For i = 0 To m - 1
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            inputv(i, j) = s(i + 1, j + 1).Value
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```